# How to set keys as first element of array

Tags: php, arrays, xlsxwriter

I'm exporting php arrays to Excel using `XLSXWriter`.

```
$data = array(
   array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'John Doe'),
   array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Jane Doe'),
   array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Will Smith'),
);

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->writeSheet($data);
$writer->writeToFile('path/and/filename.xlsx');
```

It outputs in excel like this:

```
0   |   John Doe
1   |   Jane Doe
2   |   Will Smith
```

That's ok, but I also need my array keys as first row like this:

```
id  |   name
2   |   Will Smith
0   |   John Doe
1   |   Jane Doe
2   |   Will Smith
```

So I did this:

```
    $headings = array_keys($data[0]);
    array_unshift($data,$headings);
```

It works, but is there a better way?

Comment: is there a better way is a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What your doing is fine, you could also initialise the header first, just incase no result get added to the array. Not sure its worth answering as you may obviously be aware of doing that already. https://3v4l.org/i6ha3

Comment: Thank's! Did not know of Code Review - will check it. Sometimes it's good to get a confirmation that what I'm doing is right. I was just wondering if there was a less "manual" way of getting the keys from a multi-dimentional array than: `array_keys($data[0])`

Answer (score 1):

What about **writeSheetRow**

```
    $data = array(
       array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'John Doe'),
       array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Jane Doe'),
       array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Will Smith'),
    );

    $writer = new XLSXWriter();
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1',['id','name']);
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1',end($data));
    $writer->writeSheet($data);
    $writer->writeToFile('path/and/filename.xlsx');
```

Output

```
id | name
 2 |  Will Smith 
 0 |  John Doe 
 1 |  Jane Doe 
 2 |  Will Smith
```

Adding last row first then add whole array to file.
Hope this works.